# Python NET call C# method which has a return value and an out parameter

Tags: c#, python, python-3.x, out, python.net

I'm having the following static C# method

```
public static bool TryParse (string s, out double result)
```

which I would like to call from Python using the Python NET package.

```
import clr
from System import Double
r0 = Double.IsNaN(12.3) # works

r1, d1 = Double.TryParse("12.3") # fails! TypeError: No method matches given arguments. This works in IronPython.

d2 = 0.0
r2, d2 = Double.TryParse("12.3", d2) # fails! TypeError: No method matches given arguments
```

Any idea?

**Update**

I found the following answer, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19600349/7556646.

> CPython using PythonNet does basically the same thing. The easy way to
>   do out parameters is to not pass them and accept them as extra return
>   values, and for ref parameters to pass the input values as arguments
>   and accept the output values as extra return values.

This would claim that `r1, d1 = Double.TryParse("12.3")` should work, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had to address a similar problem recently with using [Python for .NET](http://pythonnet.github.io/), let me share with you what I have found out.

You need to pass as many arguments as the method requires to. Since the concept of `out` arguments (= passed by refence) doesn't apply to Python, the trick is to pass some **dummy arguments** of the expected type.

The method call is going to return first the values that it is supposed to return, **and** the `out` values.

For my use case, the C# method I was calling did not return anything originally (void method), yet, the Python call returned first `None` and then the `out` values I was after, which is the expected behaviour as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19600349/7556646).

Your first attempt could not work because you pass only one argument, while the method expects two, be they `out` or `ref` arguments.

```
r1, d1 = Double.TryParse("12.3")
```

Your second attempt could not work either because the type of the dummy argument does not match with the type expected by the method, in that case `Double`.

```
d2 = 0.0
r2, d2 = Double.TryParse("12.3", d)
```

This will do the trick:

```
import clr
from System import Double
dummy_out = Double(0.)
returned_val, real_out = Double.TryParse("12.3", dummy_out)
```

You can observe that this last line does not have any effect on `dummy_out` by checking its `id` before and after the call.

Hence, a shorter version of the code you need would be:

```
returned_val, real_out = Double.TryParse("12.3", Double(0.))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My second attempt was `r2, d2 = Double.TryParse("12.3", d2)`, so d2 is defined. I'll edit my question. Sorry my fault. I still get the the following error: `TypeError: No method matches given arguments`.

Comment: I tried to get your code working. It does work if you follow what I wrote, but there was one thing I did not get correctly, which is that the types of the dummy `out` arguments **must** be the same as the ones the method expects. This works `returned_val, real_out = Double.TryParse("12.3", Double(0.))`